# How can I use a local variable in a method from another method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void UserYoutubeService()
{
    var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
    });
}
```

And I want to use the variable `youtubeService` in this method:

```
static List<string> videosList = new List<string>();

public async void RetrieveUploadsList()
{
    UserCredentials();
    UserYoutubeService();

    var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
}
```

I'm using the method `UserYoutubeService` in other places in my code but now I need to use the local variable `youtubeService` properties in the method `RetrieveUploadsList`. How can I pass the variable `youtubeService` out of the `UserYoutubeService`?

Comment: Have you tried returning dynamic. private dynamic UserYoutubeService(){ return new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to return the value you want from `UserYoutubeService`, as in:

```
private YouTubeService UserYoutubeService() // <-- Note return type
{
    return new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
    });
}
```

Which you would use like this:

```
public async void RetrieveUploadsList()
{
    UserCredentials();
    var youtubeService = UserYoutubeService(); // <--- Change is here

    var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
    ...
```